# How to make Bootstrap "Cards" Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap recently offers a features called "Cards" everything is cool until it reaches the 747px viewport. See image below.

[image]

As you can see it all mess up, the container doesn't fit. Is there any CSS fix that we can do make sure they are looking good from 747px and below???

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #1</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-center">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/card2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #2</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card card-inverse card-success text-center">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/card3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #3</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card card-inverse card-info text-center">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/card4.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #4</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Check out my JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/a9wav5g1/1/

Any idea??? How to fix this?

Comment: why don't you use `.col-xs` class and `.col-sm` class for mobile and tablet devices

Comment: @Amit singh: Can you show me some example of my jsfiddle codes?

Answer (score 13):

If your talking about just the images not fitting the containing div just add

```
img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

to the images you need **or** the class `img-responsive`

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/WQQZVQ?editors=110

More specifically

```
.card-img-top{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Also for the conatiner div if you need it full width just add `<div class="container-fluid">`

Comment: or you may like this utility class class="w-100"   http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/sizing-and-positioning/

Answer (score 6):

You should be more specific with what you need, but I think this helps:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
img {
    width:100%;
}
.container {
    max-width:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.col-md-3{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
}
```

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-center">

            </div>
        </div>
```

...

https://jsfiddle.net/6hpqo2u8/1/

You can also update you html:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">...</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this out for all screen sizes `lg`,`md`,`sm` and `xs`

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


  </head>

  <body>


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg 3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #1</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg 3 col-md-3  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-center">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #2</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg 3 col-md-3  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-success text-center">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #3</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg 3 col-md-3  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-info text-center">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #4</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Put your css in here */
/*
Tutorial Name: Bootstrap 4 Tutorial
Author: Samuel Dalusung
*/

@import 'main.css';


/* GENERAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#777;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:1.7;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    color:#333;
    line-height:1.4;
    font-weight:700;
}

.mx-width {
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

a,a:hover {
    color:#563d7c;
    text-decoration:none;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}

header {
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

.intro {
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:60px;
    line-height:1;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff
}

.learn {
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:27px;
    line-height:1.4;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff;
}

.jumbotron-fluid {
    padding:0;
}


/* PARALLAX
-------------------------------------------------*/
.parallax {
    text-align:center;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed!important;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.parallax-pattern-overlay {
    background-image:url(../img/pattern.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}


/* HEADING
-------------------------------------------------*/
.heading {
    padding-bottom:15px;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:80px;
}

.heading h2 {
    font-weight:600;
    font-family:'Raleway';
    font-size:40px;
    color:#333;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}

.heading h2::first-letter {
    color:#563d7c;
    font-weight:700;
}

.heading h3 {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.7;
}

#site-title {
    max-width:150px;
}


/* CONTACT
-------------------------------------------------*/
input.form-control {
    background:#fff;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
    color:#000;
    padding:15px 30px;
    margin-right:3%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    outline:none;
    border-radius: 0;
}



textarea.form-control {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
    padding:15px 30px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    outline:none;
    height:200px;
    border-radius: 0;
}

button.contact.submit {
    background:#333;
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    border:none!important;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:15px 45px;
}

button.contact.submit:hover {
    background:#563d7c;
}

.form-control:focus{
    border-color: #563d7c;
    outline: 0;
}


.done {
    display:none;
}


/* CONTACT
-------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
    background:#563d7c;
    margin-top:120px;
    position:relative
}

.footer .container {
    padding:60px 0 20px;
}

.footer ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:0;
}

.footer ul li {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color:#fff;
    line-height:45px;
    margin:0 4px;
    width:45px!important;
    height:45px!important;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.footer ul li:hover {
    background:#2a2a2a;
}

.footer ul li:hover a {
    color:#fff;
}

.footer ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    width:42px!important;
    height:42px!important;
}

.footer ul li a i {
    line-height:45px;
    color:#fff;
}

.footer p {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:.9em;
    line-height:24px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.footer a,.footer a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES
-------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {

input .contact .col-md-6{
    width:40.5%;
    margin: 15px 15px 0 58px;
}

textarea .contact .col-md-12 {
     margin: 15px 15px 0 58px;
}

button #submit .contact .submit{
    margin: 15px 15px 0 42px;
}

}
```

And if there is only the issue of image then add this

```
.card-img-top{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the class `.img-fluid` to your image. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Learn About **bootstrap grid system** and use this code you will understand the issue and this code will fix you responsive issue.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #1</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-primary text-center">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #2</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-success text-center">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #3</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-info text-center">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #4</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
            
</div>
```